# Video JS 5 VAST plugin does not work

Tags: javascript, video.js, vast

I have tried several plugins, thus, some are very old (video js 4) currently I have been testing on videojs 5 but none has worked so far.

I tried [videojs-vast-plugin](https://github.com/theonion/videojs-vast-plugin)
also tried [IMA SDK Plugin for Video.js](https://github.com/googleads/videojs-ima)

and this one [videojs-vast-vpaid plugin](https://github.com/MailOnline/videojs-vast-vpaid) which it was originally asked in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35937234/my-videojs-vast-player-failed-to-load-video-flash-ads) some of the files of this one I did not find, I used the example code on one of the answers. However, I get this error:

```
[videojs-vast-vpaid] AD ERROR: VAST Error: on VASTClient.requestVastXML, HTTP request error with status '-1' 
Object { message: "VAST Error: on VASTClient.requestVastXML, HTTP request error with status '-1'", code: 301, stack: "[23]<@http://mailonline.github.io/videojs-vast-vpaid/scripts/videojs_4.vast.vpaid.js:3774:23\ns@http://mailonline.github.io/videojs-vast-vpaid/scripts/videojs_4.vast.vpaid.js:1:246\ns/<@http://mailonline.github.io/videojs-vast-vpaid/scripts/videojs_4.vast.vpaid.js:1:305\n[33]<@http://mailonline.github.io/videojs-vast-vpaid/scripts/videojs_4.vast.vpaid.js:5173:17\ns@http://mailonline.github.io/videojs-vast-vpaid/scripts/videojs_4.vast.vpaid.js:1:246\ns/<@http://mailonline.github.io/videojs-vast-vpaid/scripts/videojs_4.vast.vpaid.js:1:305\n[30]<@http://mailonline.github.io/videojs-vast-vpaid/scripts/videojs_4.vast.vpaid.js:4685:22\ns@http://mailonline.github.io/videojs-vast-vpaid/scripts/videojs_4.vast.vpaid.js:1:246\ns/<@http://mailonline.github.io/videojs-vast-vpaid/scripts/videojs_4.vast.vpaid.js:1:305\n[18]<@http://mailonline.github.io/videojs-vast-vpaid/scripts/videojs_4.vast.vpaid.js:3249:16\ns@http://mailonline.github.io/videojs-vast-vpaid/scripts/videojs_4.vast.vpaid.js:1:246\ns/<@http://mailonline.github.io/videojs-vast-vpaid/scripts/videojs_4.vast.vpaid.js:1:305\n[15]<@http://mailonline.github.io/videojs-vast-vpaid/scripts/videojs_4.vast.vpaid.js:3077:14\ns@http://mailonline.github.io/videojs-vast-vpaid/scripts/videojs_4.vast.vpaid.js:1:246\ns/<@http://mailonline.github.io/videojs-vast-vpaid/scripts/videojs_4.vast.vpaid.js:1:305\n[22]<@http://mailonline.github.io/videojs-vast-vpaid/scripts/videojs_4.vast.vpaid.js:3467:10\ns@http://mailonline.github.io/videojs-vast-vpaid/scripts/videojs_4.vast.vpaid.js:1:246\ns/<@http://mailonline.github.io/videojs-vast-vpaid/scripts/videojs_4.vast.vpaid.js:1:305\n[39]<@http://mailonline.github.io/videojs-vast-vpaid/scripts/videojs_4.vast.vpaid.js:5925:18\ns@http://mailonline.github.io/videojs-vast-vpaid/scripts/videojs_4.vast.vpaid.js:1:246\ns/<@http://mailonline.github.io/videojs-vast-vpaid/scripts/videojs_4.vast.vpaid.js:1:305\n[49]<@http://mailonline.github.io/videojs-vast-vpaid/scripts/videojs_4.vast.vpaid.js:7889:19\ns@http://mailonline.github.io/videojs-vast-vpaid/scripts/videojs_4.vast.vpaid.js:1:246\ne@http://mailonline.github.io/videojs-vast-vpaid/scripts/videojs_4.vast.vpaid.js:1:425\n@http://mailonline.github.io/videojs-vast-vpaid/scripts/videojs_4.vast.vpaid.js:1:11\n" }
 null
consoleLogger.js:21
```

I cannot use videojs 4 because I need the [HLS plugin](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/videojs-contrib-hls/5.11.1) which did not work with version 4

is there a VAST plugin that will work with video js 5? this plugin [videojs-vast-plugin](https://github.com/theonion/videojs-vast-plugin) loads my VAST tag fine when I use an mp4 file, it does not work if I use videojs 5

Answer (score 0):

Can not leave a comment due to lacking of reputation.
Can you pls provide working vast uri?
From your vast uri sample on [this question][1]

[1]: [My videojs Vast player failed to load video flash ads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35937234/my-videojs-vast-player-failed-to-load-video-flash-ads), there is no vast response, also it does not allow ima to request:

> Failed to load https://p.algovid.com/vpvast?p=99974938&cb=undefined&d=https://h5.xcloudgame.com&w=710&h=500: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://imasdk.googleapis.com' is therefore not allowed access.

I have been using videojs-ima for serving ads for some time!